# Can't read data from a serial port ttymxc

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, modbus, rs485

So I'm trying to connect an embedded linux device with a server over a serial port connection RS485.
I'm using an USB/RS adapter to connect it to my laptop.
The server is able to receive the request and send the answer, but the client doesn't receive tha response.
to look more into it I tried to check the connection between the device and the laptop with power shell

```
PS C:\Users\oziat.VIX> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,9600,None,8,one
PS C:\Users\oziat.VIX> $port.open()
PS C:\Users\oziat.VIX> $port.ReadLine()
hello
```

from the client:

```
echo "hello" > /dev/ttymxc1
```

Mean while if I try to send data from powershell I dont receive anything from the other end

```
PS C:\Users\oziat.VIX> $port.WriteLine("Hello world")
```

```
# cat  /dev/ttymxc1
_
```

I tried to check if it's a hardware problem. I'm almost sure that it's not (giving the fact that I'm able to receive data on the server)

Out put of set serial

```
# setserial /dev/ttymxc1
/dev/ttymxc1, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 32, Flags: low_latency
#
```

I dont know why uart is set to undefined, and I wasn't able to change it

```
setserial: can't set serial info: Invalid argument
```

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: 
I was able to identify the problem, the device is shiped preconfigured on mode rs422, I had to configure it to be on mode rs485 using `ioctl()`

Comment: Have you checked if the serial port is being used by another process? Maybe you have a console spitting kernel messages... Some people experience problems with setserial, can you try stty or maybe minicom?

Comment: Do you really need RS485? RS485 is mainly intended for multidrop connection communication. If you just want to increase the distance between devices or perform high-speed, noise-resistant communication, RS422 will be easier to use. If you really use RS485, you should implement some standardized protocol rather than a non-procedural protocol like the tty console. Before that, add a description of whether the connection method is half duplex or full duplex.

Answer (score 1):

The driver for your serial port does not seem to be working with setserial.

See, from the man pages:

> setserial gets the information via an ioctl() call. In case the driver 
>   for your device does not support TIOCGSERIAL, the "invalid argument" is 
>   returned.

I think you need to use `stty` or something like minicom instead.